# Constructing cell complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to construct a cell complex that has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_3}$.

Is there an algorithm to construct a cell complex from given fundamental group?

Comment: Do you know a space which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_k$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese My guess is it would be k-gon with possible identifications on each edge?

Comment: Remember $\pi_1(M\times N)\cong \pi_1 M \times \pi_1 N$

Comment: @ToInfinity: Do you know any spaces with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: @ToInfinity: Right. Just so I make sure we're on the same page, how do you know that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I used Van Kampen to see the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}p^2$.

Comment: @ToInfinity: OK. So from van Kampen picture, you can see that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be obtained by attaching a disc to a circle by a degree two map on the boundary. Think about what would happen if you change the degree of the attaching map.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I don't quite get it yet. Could you explain little bit more? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ToInfinity: How are you viewing $\mathbb{RP}^2$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I use this identification on the first to page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) when thinking about the real projective plane. But I don't think I have a good intuition of that space.

Comment: @ToInfinity: For the purposes of this question, I think it is better to consider the identification given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/539370/39599).